# SQL 'Group by' Query with 'distinct' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a query out of three tables with two joins
and the following table is the result.

| Rolename | User | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Role 2777 | User 1542 | 0 |
| Role 2965 | User 922 | 1 |
| Role 2777 | User 1444 | 12 |
| Role 2965 | User 922 | 1 |
| Role 1234 | User 922 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**My goal is to have the sum of transactions per user.**

Originally there are dublicates in the 'Rolename' column whose transactions only has to be counted once. That's why I had to do the distinct statement.

I already tried some ways of nested querys with 'group by' but nothing worked properly.
Please tell me how I can get the result I'm looking for.

```
Select distinct(roles.Role_Name) as Role_Name, udim.Username, (roles.Count_Tcodes) as Transactions
    from Table1 as udim
    left join Table2 as RoleToUser
    on udim.Username = RoleToUser.Username
    left join Table3 as roles
    on RoleToUser.Role_Name = roles.Role_Name
```

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: It, in truth, appears that you think that `DISTINCT` is a function; this is not true. `DISTINCT` is a *set operation*, it's not `DISTINCT ({Column List})` or `DISTINCT ({Column})` it's `SELECT DISTINCT {Column List}`.

Comment: Your syntax also suggests you think `DISTINCT` applies to a single column.

Comment: What are you actual expected results for your sample data?

Comment: Back to the question: `My goal is to have the sum of transactions per user.` So you don't want it broken down by role? If you don't want role in the result, why is it there? If you do want role in the result, and you only want one row per user, which role should be shown? Hint: _show_ the result you're looking for. So far you've only shown the result you _don't_ want. Always useful to [build an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Every role has a fixed number of transactions linked to it.
I want to know the sum of transactions per user. But sometimes a user has a role more than once. Then I only want those transactions to be counted once to the summation.

Comment: So `role_name, user_name, SUM(transactions)... group by role_name, user_name`?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for.
Maybe my goal was unclear:
When a role is assigned to a user more than once, its transactions has to be added to the total transactions per user only once.

The goal is a table with each user and their total amount of transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some useful comments I was able to figure it out by myself.
I used **Rownumber()** for creating an hierarchie for non-unique TCodes.
Then I filtered by **rownumber = 1**. This way there were only unique TCodes per Role.

I did it in three steps(views) because it's more convenient.

```
Create View View1 as
    Select a.Username, RoleToTCode.TCode
       from Table_a as a
       left join Table_b as b
       on a.Username = b.Username
       left join Table_c as c
       on b.Role_Name = c.Role_Name


Create View View2 as
    Select * ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Username, TCode order by Username, TCode) Rownumber 
       from View1

   
CreatView View3 as
    Select Username, count(TCode) UniqueTCodes
        from View2
        where RowNumber = 1
        group by Username
        order by Username
```